# ffmpeg on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, ffmpeg

Has anyone used ffmpeg on iphone? How do I go about compiling ffmpeg on iphone? And on OS X?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using FFMPEG library with iPhone SDK for video encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679649/using-ffmpeg-library-with-iphone-sdk-for-video-encoding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OS X, it is as simple as running macports,

for the iphone the situation is a little more complex, you'll need to run the ./configure script your self and use the --cross-prefix option to build binaries for the arm processor, you'll also need to change the make file to build static libraries.
You'll also need to manage all the dependencies your self and repeat the same process for each required lib.

Finally keep in mind that ffmpeg is licensed under LGPL so if you statically link your iphone app to it you'll need to release your source code (under some interpretations of the LGPL)