# How to add image in video file in iphone by programming?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented one iphone application in which I want to editing video file.In which I want to add one image at the end of the video.Is it possible.
If possible then please give me idea abut that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, for example, ffmpeq library. This is powerfully native C project that allow you to modify every frame from video, set masks and more interests features. 
See more on

- [FFmpeg site](http://www.ffmpeg.org)
- [Using FFMPEG library with iPhone SDK
  for video encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679649/using-ffmpeg-library-with-iphone-sdk-for-video-encoding)
- [ffmpeg4iphone](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg4iphone/)

Comment: But if you don't need in ton of additional sources you can make fake like this - you simply show UIImageView with your image after video played. Setup previously non-style for MPMoviewPlayerController