# Converting video to .mp4 format within the app before uploading to server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, upload, type-conversion

Can u help me in this issue ? I am recording videos through my appliction.Is it posiible to record the video in the mp4 format or otherwise i need to convert it to .mp4 format recording it in default format before uploading it to the server? Is there any possibilities to convert the video to .mp4 format through coding, if possible please post a sample for it.

Comment: Otherwise is it possible to save the video in .mp4 format after recording in the device itself?

Comment: converting videos on a mobile device is a really really bad idea, as it's a cpu-intensive operation that will drain your battery in no time

Answer (score 0):

See [Using FFMPEG library with iPhone SDK for video encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679649/using-ffmpeg-library-with-iphone-sdk-for-video-encoding)