# How to play FLV file programmatically on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, video-streaming, flv

I am going to play flv file on iPhone with ffmpeg library.

The codec of the file is H.264 and video codec is AVC HL.

Perhaps other ideas without ffmpeg are OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be of help.

[Using FFMPEG library with iPhone SDK for video encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679649/using-ffmpeg-library-with-iphone-sdk-for-video-encoding)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I read the article about iFrameExtractor project. I also guess that the project will be able to play flv file. But I can't compile it with ffmpeg library errors.