# problem compiling ffmpeg for iFrameExtractor

Tags: iphone, ios, ffmpeg, armv6

I'm trying to compile the ffmpeg by using the make and build files in [iFrameExtractor example](https://github.com/lajos/iFrameExtractor). firstly i tried to follow the readme file on the github, which only says to run the `./build_universal` in ffmpeg folder. it did not work

i then tried to follow the info in INSTALL without success. i then tried doing the stuff in INSTALL followed by the `./build_universal` which didn't work. All the *.a files that are imported to the project exists until the end of the build sequence. when the **lipo** commands in build_universal are run, which i guess concat the .a files for the different architectures(?). anyhow these leave the following errors:

```
lipo: specifed architecture type (armv6) for file (armv6/libavcodec.a) does not match it's cputype (16777223) and cpusubtype (3) (should be cputype (12) and cpusubtype (6))
lipo: specifed architecture type (armv6) for file (armv6/libavdevice.a) does not match it's cputype (16777223) and cpusubtype (3) (should be cputype (12) and cpusubtype (6))
lipo: specifed architecture type (armv6) for file (armv6/libavformat.a) does not match it's cputype (16777223) and cpusubtype (3) (should be cputype (12) and cpusubtype (6))
lipo: specifed architecture type (armv6) for file (armv6/libavutil.a) does not match it's cputype (16777223) and cpusubtype (3) (should be cputype (12) and cpusubtype (6))
lipo: specifed architecture type (armv6) for file (armv6/libswscale.a) does not match it's cputype (16777223) and cpusubtype (3) (should be cputype (12) and cpusubtype (6))
```

i can get the project to compile for simulator if i only use `./build_armv7` but if i run the universal the .a files are removed in the end. and only using doesn't work to build for iphone 4 .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a week of trial and error, I was finally able to create the ffmpeg universal libraries and successfully compile and run iFrameExtractor for the device as well as the simulator.

To compile and run the project on your iPhone device OR simulator:

1) open Terminal

2) clone the repository: git clone git://github.com/lajos/iFrameExtractor.git

3) go to the ffmpeg folder in the project: cd iFrameExtractor/ffmpeg

4) run: ./configure

5) Edit the build scripts (build_armv6, build_armv7, build_i386) as follows:

These scripts assume you are using iOS SDK 5.0 on Xcode 4.2.

build_armv6:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

if (! -d armv6) mkdir armv6
if (! -d lib) mkdir lib

rm armv6/*.a

make clean

./configure \
--disable-bzlib --disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffserver --disable-mmx \
--cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
--as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' \
--enable-cross-compile --target-os=darwin \
--arch=arm --cpu=arm1176jzf-s \
--sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk \
--extra-ldflags="-arch armv6 -L//Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib/system" \
--extra-cflags="-arch armv6"

make

mv libavcodec/libavcodec.a armv6/
mv libavdevice/libavdevice.a armv6/
mv libavformat/libavformat.a armv6/
mv libavutil/libavutil.a armv6/
mv libswscale/libswscale.a armv6/

rm lib/*.a

cp armv6/*.a lib/
```

build_armv7:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

if (! -d armv7) mkdir armv7
if (! -d lib) mkdir lib

rm armv7/*.a

make clean

./configure \
--disable-bzlib --disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffserver --disable-mmx \
--cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
--as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' \
--enable-cross-compile --target-os=darwin \
--arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-pic \
--sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk \
--extra-ldflags="-arch armv7 -    L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib/system" \
--extra-cflags="-arch armv7"

make

mv libavcodec/libavcodec.a armv7/
mv libavdevice/libavdevice.a armv7/
mv libavformat/libavformat.a armv7/
mv libavutil/libavutil.a armv7/
mv libswscale/libswscale.a armv7/

rm lib/*.a

cp armv7/*.a lib/
```

build_i386:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

if (! -d i386) mkdir i386
if (! -d lib) mkdir lib

rm i386/*.a

make clean

./configure \
--disable-bzlib --disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffserver --disable-mmx \
--cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
--as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl     /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' \
--sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk \
--extra-ldflags="-arch i386 -L//Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/system" \
--extra-cflags="-arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fasm-blocks -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40000 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -fvisibility=hidden -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -gdwarf-2"

make

mv libavcodec/libavcodec.a i386/
mv libavdevice/libavdevice.a i386/
mv libavformat/libavformat.a i386/
mv libavutil/libavutil.a i386/
mv libswscale/libswscale.a i386/

rm lib/*.a

cp i386/*.a lib/
```

6) build the ffmpeg libraries: ./build_universal

7) open the xcode project and run it on your iPhone device or simulator

These steps work perfectly for me. I hope this will help others struggling to get the ffmpeg libraries working for iOS.

Comment: can you contact with me, i need some outsource programming in this case (oleksiivinogradov Skype) or oleksiivinogradov@me.com email

Comment: Hi @Far Pointer,i followed all your steps but had no success compiling the iFrameExtractor.I am using Xcode 4.2.Can u help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

i downloaded the latest ffmpeg repository and used the following to compile only for armv6 and armv7. I couldn't get it working for i386, i receive errors that the cputype and subcputype are wrong. apparently the cputype is supposed to be x86 and subcputype should be intel.

anyhow i used the following build scripts to compile for the arm architectures:

build script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

SCRIPT_DIR=$( (cd -P $(dirname $0) && pwd) )
DIST_DIR_BASE=${DIST_DIR_BASE:="$SCRIPT_DIR/dist"}

if [ -d ffmpeg ]
then
  echo "Found ffmpeg source directory, no need to fetch from git..."
else
  echo "Fetching ffmpeg from git://git.videolan.org/ffmpeg.git..."
  git clone git://git.videolan.org/ffmpeg.git
fi

ARCHS=${ARCHS:-"armv6 armv7"}

for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
    FFMPEG_DIR=ffmpeg-$ARCH
    if [ -d $FFMPEG_DIR ]
    then
      echo "Removing old directory $FFMPEG_DIR"
      rm -rf $FFMPEG_DIR
    fi
    echo "Copying source for $ARCH to directory $FFMPEG_DIR"
    cp -a ffmpeg $FFMPEG_DIR

    cd $FFMPEG_DIR

    DIST_DIR=$DIST_DIR_BASE-$ARCH
    mkdir -p $DIST_DIR

    case $ARCH in
        armv6)
            EXTRA_FLAGS="--enable-cross-compile --target-os=darwin --arch=arm --cpu=arm1176jzf-s"
            EXTRA_CFLAGS="-arch $ARCH"
            EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-arch $ARCH"
            ;;
        armv7)
            EXTRA_FLAGS="--enable-cross-compile --target-os=darwin --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-pic"
            EXTRA_CFLAGS="-arch $ARCH"
            EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-arch $ARCH"
            ;;
        x86_64)
            EXTRA_CC_FLAGS="-mdynamic-no-pic"
            ;;
    esac

    echo "Configuring ffmpeg for $ARCH..."
    ./configure \
    --prefix=$DIST_DIR \
    --extra-ldflags=-L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib/system \
    --disable-bzlib \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
    --sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk \
    --extra-ldflags="$EXTRA_LDFLAGS" \
    --extra-cflags="$EXTRA_CFLAGS" \
    $EXTRA_FLAGS

    echo "Installing ffmpeg for $ARCH..."
    make && make install

    cd $SCRIPT_DIR

    if [ -d $DIST_DIR/bin ]
    then
      rm -rf $DIST_DIR/bin
    fi
    if [ -d $DIST_DIR/share ]
    then
      rm -rf $DIST_DIR/share
    fi
done
```

and combine libs script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

ARCHS="armv6 armv7"

for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
  if [ -d dist-$ARCH ]
  then
    MAIN_ARCH=$ARCH
  fi
done

if [ -z "$MAIN_ARCH" ]
then
  echo "Please compile an architecture"
  exit 1
fi


OUTPUT_DIR="dist-uarch"
rm -rf $OUTPUT_DIR

mkdir -p $OUTPUT_DIR/lib $OUTPUT_DIR/include

for LIB in dist-$MAIN_ARCH/lib/*.a
do
  LIB=`basename $LIB`
  LIPO_CREATE=""
  for ARCH in $ARCHS
  do
    if [ -d dist-$ARCH ]
    then
      LIPO_CREATE="$LIPO_CREATE-arch $ARCH dist-$ARCH/lib/$LIB "
    fi
  done
  OUTPUT="$OUTPUT_DIR/lib/$LIB"
  echo "Creating: $OUTPUT"
  lipo -create $LIPO_CREATE -output $OUTPUT
  lipo -info $OUTPUT
done

echo "Copying headers from dist-$MAIN_ARCH..."
cp -R dist-$MAIN_ARCH/include/* $OUTPUT_DIR/include
```

then i import the .a files from BUILD-FOLDER/dist-uarch and it builds in xcode like a charm!

Comment: Built fine but now have link errors:  (there are 39, here is a sample)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_ff_vector_fmul_vfp", referenced from:
      _ff_dsputil_init_vfp in libavcodec.a(dsputil_init_vfp.o)
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.3.1.o
  "_av_solve_lls", referenced from:
      _ff_lpc_calc_coefs in libavcodec.a(lpc.o)
   "_ff_float_to_int16_vfp", referenced from:
      _ff_dsputil_init_vfp in libavcodec.a(dsputil_init_vfp.o)
  
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Comment: feel like i got this one too, not quite sure. how are the imports? might be that you have to add another search path for imports. click the target -> build settings tab -> search paths -> and change the header/library search path to match the place of the built files!

Comment: This worked for me as well. Nice work! The additional steps i took were to change the sdk version in the script. I also needed to add "--disable-asm" to the flags. Finally, I needed to update my header search paths.

Answer (score 1):

**building FFMPEG for iOS 5.1**

hope this will help you to build latest FFMPEG for iOS 5.1

```
git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg

cd ffmpeg

./build_universal
```

note: you have to create build_* scripts first, to do this see code below

**script for ARMV7 - create file build_armv7**

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

if (! -d armv7) mkdir armv7
if (! -d lib) mkdir lib

rm armv7/*.a

make clean

./configure --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --target-os=darwin --cc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc --as='gas-preprocessor.pl /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk --cpu=cortex-a8 --extra-cflags='-arch armv7' --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk' --enable-pic

make

mv libavcodec/libavcodec.a armv7/
mv libavdevice/libavdevice.a armv7/
mv libavformat/libavformat.a armv7/
mv libavutil/libavutil.a armv7/
mv libswscale/libswscale.a armv7/

rm lib/*.a

cp armv7/*.a lib/
```

**script for ARMV6 - create file build_armv6**

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

if (! -d armv6) mkdir armv6
if (! -d lib) mkdir lib

rm armv6/*.a

make clean

./configure --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --target-os=darwin --cc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc --as='gas-preprocessor.pl /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk --cpu=arm1176jzf-s --extra-cflags='-arch armv6' --extra-ldflags='-arch armv6 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk'

make

mv libavcodec/libavcodec.a armv6/
mv libavdevice/libavdevice.a armv6/
mv libavformat/libavformat.a armv6/
mv libavutil/libavutil.a armv6/
mv libswscale/libswscale.a armv6/

rm lib/*.a

cp armv6/*.a lib/
```

**script for simulator - create file build_i386**

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

if (! -d i386) mkdir i386
if (! -d lib) mkdir lib

rm i386/*.a

make clean

./configure \
--disable-bzlib --disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffserver --disable-mmx \
--cc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
--as='gas-preprocessor.pl /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' \
--sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk \
--extra-ldflags="-arch i386 -L//Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/usr/lib/system" \
--extra-cflags="-arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fasm-blocks -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40000 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -fvisibility=hidden -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -gdwarf-2"

make

mv libavcodec/libavcodec.a i386/
mv libavdevice/libavdevice.a i386/
mv libavformat/libavformat.a i386/
mv libavutil/libavutil.a i386/
mv libswscale/libswscale.a i386/

rm lib/*.a

cp i386/*.a lib/
```

**script for universal build (will merge libraries into one universal) - create file build_universal**

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

source ./build_armv6
source ./build_armv7
source ./build_i386

if (! -d universal) mkdir universal
if (! -d lib) mkdir lib

rm universal/*.a

lipo -create -arch armv6 armv6/libavcodec.a -arch armv7 armv7/libavcodec.a -arch i386 i386/libavcodec.a -output universal/libavcodec.a
lipo -create -arch armv6 armv6/libavdevice.a -arch armv7 armv7/libavdevice.a -arch i386 i386/libavdevice.a -output universal/libavdevice.a
lipo -create -arch armv6 armv6/libavformat.a -arch armv7 armv7/libavformat.a -arch i386 i386/libavformat.a -output universal/libavformat.a
lipo -create -arch armv6 armv6/libavutil.a -arch armv7 armv7/libavutil.a -arch i386 i386/libavutil.a -output universal/libavutil.a
lipo -create -arch armv6 armv6/libswscale.a -arch armv7 armv7/libswscale.a -arch i386 i386/libswscale.a -output universal/libswscale.a

rm lib/*.a

cp universal/*.a lib/
```