# using ffmpeg with xcode

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problem compiling ffmpeg for iFrameExtractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994151/problem-compiling-ffmpeg-for-iframeextractor)

I have successfully run FFMPEG in the terminal on a Mac, but I have problem with Xcode. I used iFrameExtractor but I found these errors:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/training/Desktop/iFrameExtractor/ffmpeg/lib/libavformat.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/training/Desktop/iFrameExtractor/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/training/Desktop/iFrameExtractor/ffmpeg/lib/libavdevice.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/training/Desktop/iFrameExtractor/ffmpeg/lib/libavutil.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/training/Desktop/iFrameExtractor/ffmpeg/lib/libswscale.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_av_register_all", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor initWithVideo:] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_av_open_input_file", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor initWithVideo:] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_av_find_stream_info", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor initWithVideo:] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_avcodec_find_decoder", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor initWithVideo:] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_avcodec_open", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor initWithVideo:] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_avcodec_alloc_frame", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor initWithVideo:] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_avpicture_free", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor setupScaler] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[VideoFrameExtractor dealloc] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_sws_freeContext", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor setupScaler] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[VideoFrameExtractor dealloc] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_avpicture_alloc", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor setupScaler] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_sws_getContext", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor setupScaler] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_avformat_seek_file", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor seekTime:] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_avcodec_flush_buffers", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor seekTime:] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_av_free", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor dealloc] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_avcodec_close", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor dealloc] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_av_close_input_file", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor dealloc] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_av_read_frame", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor stepFrame] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_avcodec_decode_video2", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor stepFrame] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_av_free_packet", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor stepFrame] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
  "_sws_scale", referenced from:
      -[VideoFrameExtractor convertFrameToRGB] in VideoFrameExtractor.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since iPhone applications are targeted for the ARM architecture, you'll have to recompile the ffmpeg library for ARM.

You should use the `--arch=arm` option when configuring the ffmpeg build.

Comment: how can i do this please tell me the whole procedure.I am using xcode4.2.1 & mac 10.7.2...