# iFrameExtractor fails to build library for armv7 using XCode 4.3.3 & iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

I have downloaded code to build with XCode 4.3.3 for iOS 5.1 from this link - https://github.com/lajos/iFrameExtractor
I am successfully able to build the libraries for FFmpeg using build_universal script. But it always builds the libraries for X86_64 architecture. Checked with lipo -info command.

Also tried the build script from the link - http://stexgroup.com/blog/ffmpeg-for-iphone-ios-xcode4.3-build-script. It also builds libraries for X86_64 architecture.

I changed the scripts as per this post - [problem compiling ffmpeg for iFrameExtractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994151/problem-compiling-ffmpeg-for-iframeextractor)

But nothing is working for me.

The build script for armv7 [iFrameExtractor] is as following

```
./configure \
--disable-bzlib --disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffserver --disable-mmx \
--cc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
--as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' \
--enable-cross-compile --target-os=darwin \
--arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-pic \
--sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk \
--extra-ldflags="-arch armv7 -    L//Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/usr/lib" \
--extra-cflags="-arch armv7"
```

Can anybody guide me what can be the issue, considering the same thing is working for everyone else?

Answer (score 0):

With the following scripts i am able to build the libraries. These scripts are modified version of scripts share by Far Pointer in this link - [problem compiling ffmpeg for iFrameExtractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994151/problem-compiling-ffmpeg-for-iframeextractor)

armv6

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

if (! -d armv6) mkdir armv6
if (! -d lib) mkdir lib

rm armv6/*.a

make clean

./configure \
--disable-bzlib --disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffserver --disable-mmx \
--cc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
--as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' \
--enable-cross-compile --target-os=darwin \
--arch=arm --cpu=arm1176jzf-s \
--sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk \
--extra-ldflags="-arch armv6 -L//Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/usr/lib/system" \
--extra-cflags="-arch armv6"

make

mv libavcodec/libavcodec.a armv6/
mv libavdevice/libavdevice.a armv6/
mv libavformat/libavformat.a armv6/
mv libavutil/libavutil.a armv6/
mv libswscale/libswscale.a armv6/

rm lib/*.a

cp armv6/*.a lib/
```

armv7

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

if (! -d armv7) mkdir armv7
if (! -d lib) mkdir lib

rm armv7/*.a

make clean

./configure \
--disable-bzlib --disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffserver --disable-mmx \
--cc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
--as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' \
--enable-cross-compile --target-os=darwin \
--arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-pic \
--sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk \
--extra-ldflags="-arch armv7 -    L//Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/usr/lib/system" \
--extra-cflags="-arch armv7"

make

mv libavcodec/libavcodec.a armv7/
mv libavdevice/libavdevice.a armv7/
mv libavformat/libavformat.a armv7/
mv libavutil/libavutil.a armv7/
mv libswscale/libswscale.a armv7/

rm lib/*.a

cp armv7/*.a lib/
```

i386

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

if (! -d i386) mkdir i386
if (! -d lib) mkdir lib

rm i386/*.a

make clean

./configure \
--disable-bzlib --disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffserver --disable-mmx \
--cc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
--as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' \
--sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk \
--extra-ldflags="-arch i386 -L//Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/usr/lib/system" \
--extra-cflags="-arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fasm-blocks -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40000 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -fvisibility=hidden -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -gdwarf-2"

make

mv libavcodec/libavcodec.a i386/
mv libavdevice/libavdevice.a i386/
mv libavformat/libavformat.a i386/
mv libavutil/libavutil.a i386/
mv libswscale/libswscale.a i386/

rm lib/*.a

cp i386/*.a lib/
```

Now the problem is that all the scripts build libraries for armv6 architecture. Does anyone encounter such problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this framework if you like

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/ffmpegDecoder

and our framextractor started with iframeextrator as a base but then diverged to use
avfoundation

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/FFPlayer-tests

There is also no reason you just can substitute our ffmpeg framework for the ffmpeg build in iframeextractor

```
{
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#include <ffmpegdecoder/libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <ffmpegdecoder/libswscale/swscale.h>
}
```

the framework is based on ffmpeg 8.3 , which we find to be a bit more stable for the current version especially for ip camera feeds. their are some mods, these are in ffmpeg.zip file in the frames-test project.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted how to integrate ffmpeg in all versions of ios. just check it

[FFMPEG integration on iphone/ ipad project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854190/ffmpeg-integration-on-iphone-ipad-project/15429359#15429359)

finally we will get ffmpeg universal library and #include files. add it to your project and follow those steps given in that link. iframeextractor is working fine for me