# playing AVI and Divx in iOS

Tags: ios, video-encoding

I'm seeing this app "Azul Media Player" that plays AVI files, divx, wmv, and a lot more video files. How do they do that? How can I play AVI videos in my app? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS does not support divx and wmv files natively, so most likely they are using a third-party library to do the decoding.  For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679649/using-ffmpeg-library-with-iphone-sdk-for-video-encoding) has some links about getting FFmpeg embedded in an iPhone app.  (You would have to be careful about the licensing, because FFmpeg is licensed under the LGPL, although with any of these open source libraries, you will want to read the license closely.)