# How to play FLV in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, youtube, flv

I need to show YouTube FLV videos inside my iPhone app.
Is there a way to do it? Do i need specific libraries/players or is it impossible and need to convert the source files in another format?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679649/using-ffmpeg-library-with-iphone-sdk-for-video-encoding

Comment: May be this link can help you.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679649/using-ffmpeg-library-with-iphone-sdk-for-video-encoding][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679649/using-ffmpeg-library-with-iphone-sdk-for-video-encoding

Comment: just convert them to Quicktime/H264. FLV is soooo 2002